# Preserve state between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two different activities, ActA which is my main Activity, and ActB. I get to ActB from ActA through a menu voice. If I press the back button (either software or hardware) in ActB the app come back to ActA preserving my previous state in this activity. If instead I press the up button in the activity bar, the ActA reset its state. How can I prevent this to happen?

Don't know if this could ever help, but this is some code:
Activity A

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_save:
            startActivity (new Intent (this, Save.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.action_about:
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Manifest for Activity B:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.myapplication2.app.Save"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_save"
        android:parentActivityName="com.myapplication2.app.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.myapplication2.app.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: Consider launch your activity A using different mode, maybe `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

Comment: Activity A is main activity, my fault not specifying this before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this switch case:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: finish(); return true;
 }
```

The way it works, Up `(android.R.id.home)` by default calls your `Activity` with the same `Intent`, and depending on how you handled `onCreate` and `onResume` it may be the case that you're recreating your views. If you change Up behaviour to match Back the state is preserved.

You won't need `android:parentActivityName` or `meta-data`, just add

```
getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

somewhere on your lifecycle code.

Comment: Clear and simple, every answer should look like this! Thank you!

Comment: There are ramifications tho, the Up model is there to support the case where A->B->C->D and D can Up to A if A is its parent and Back to C. If your navigation is mostly lineal you'll be fine.

Comment: Basically I only have those two activities by now, so no problems here :D